# Set alarmManager not to repeat

Tags: android

Is there anything about, setting alarmmanager activate only ones?

```
setRepeating ();
```

How to set this activate only *ones?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the alarm to repeat, don't include the code

```
setRepeating();
```

Comment: Yea, can you please upvote the answer if you found it useful?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to activate the `AlarmManager` only once, you should use:

```
set(int type, long triggerAtMillis, PendingIntent operation);
```

instead of:

```
setRepeating(int type, long triggerAtMillis, 
    long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation);
```